# Cannot read property '$scope' of undefined AngularJs Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting an error in my angularJS and I am not not sure why.  I am trying to use the $inject Property Annotation method described here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

I get the following error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$scope' of undefined on line 44 which is

```
CarouselController.$inject['$scope'];
```

My App.JS looks like:

```
var bloxApp = angular.module('bloxApp', ['bloxApp.form', 'bloxApp.carousel']);
bloxApp.config(['$logProvider', function ($logProvider) {
$logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
}]);
```

My blox-app.js looks like this:  (app.js is loaded first, blox-app.js loaded immediately following:)

```
    angular.module('bloxApp.common'[]);;angular.module('bloxApp').factory('lodash', ['$window', function (window) {
return window._;
}]);;(function () {
angular.module('bloxApp.form', []);
})();;(function () {
var FormController = function ($scope, $window, $http, _) {


    $scope.choices = [{ id: 'choice1' }, { id: 'choice2' }, { id: 'choice3' }];

    $scope.addNewPiece = function () {
        var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
        $scope.choices.push({ 'id': 'choice' + newItemNo });
    };

    $scope.removePiece = function (int_id) {
        var newItemNo = $scope.choices.id;
        _.pull($scope.choices, _.find($scope.choices, { id: int_id }));
    };
}
FormController.$inject = ['$scope', '$window', '$http', 'lodash'];
angular.module('bloxApp.form')
    .controller('FormController', FormController);
})();
;;;(function () {
angular.module('bloxApp.carousel', []);
})();;(function () {
var CarouselController = function ($scope) {
    $scope.slides = [
          {
              image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/', text: 'hello'
          },
          {
              image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food', text: 'hello'
          },
          {
              image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports', text: 'hello'
          },
          {
              image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people', text: 'hello'
          }
    ];
}
CarouselController.$inject['$scope'];
angular.module('bloxApp.carousel')
    .controller('CarouselController', CarouselController);

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `CarouselController.$inject = ['$scope']`.

You missed the `=` so it's trying to access a property called `$scope` on the property of `$inject` on `CarouselController`, rather than setting the `$inject` property equal to `['$scope']`.

Comment: Thank you.  I looked at that for hours and totally missed it.

Comment: @Joe No problem.  Silly typos catch out everybody, sometimes just another pair of eyes help. :)